# Set locale in Console command with listener

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I want to use the `strftime` function during a console command using the locale definition in my configuration.yml file.

Since I don't have a request, session, etc during a console command, I really don't know how to achieve this in a good way without hacking it into the code. Right now my code looks like this:

```
$date = "20131210";
$dateObject = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Ymd", $date);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $this->locale);
return strftime("%e %A %G", $dateObject->getTimestamp());
```

What I actualy want is a listener that somehow sets my locale.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I know that question is a bit old but maybe someone will find the following helpful as it is not so obvious.

If your command class extends `ContainerAwareCommand` you can get the locale from configuration using `$this->getContainer()->getParameter('locale')` (I assume that you have locale defined as a parameter in `parameters.yml`.

Now the "not so obvious part": at first you should check what locales your system supports. On linux server you can check that using the following command in the console:

```
locale -a
```

It should return something similar to:

```
C
en_US.utf8
pl_PL.utf8
POSIX
```

You can only use locales that are listed by that command. If you use eg `pl_PL` without the `.utf8` part then probably it won't work.